# No me envia los datos del formulario a la base de datos usando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, registro

Estoy intentando enviar a la base de datos los datos del formulario. Cuando era solo *mail*, *password* y contraseña si todo perfecto, pero cuando agregué los demás campos de ahi no me quiso enviar los datos.

Está en 3 partes lo del modelo-vista-controlador, pero en el archivo **crud.php** donde se envía hacia las bases de datos los archivos cuando agrego los demas parametros incluidos en el *mysql* y los uno como con *usuario*, *password* y *email* no me los guarda, pero cuando solo eran esos 3 ahi si me los guardaba y tengo esa duda.

Esta es la parte hacia las bases de datos

```php
class Datos extends Conexion{

    #registro de usuario
    #-------------------------------------
    public function registroUsuarioModel($datosModel, $tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(usuario, email, password, cedula, sexo, telefono, movil, direccion, universidad, pnf, sede, vacunado) VALUES (:usuario, :email, :password, :cedula, :sexo, :telefono, :movil, :direccion, :universidad, :pnf, :sede, :vacunado)"); 

        #bindparam() vinvula variables php a un parametro de sustitucion 

        $stmt-> bindParam(":usuario",$datosModel["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":email",$datosModel["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":password",$datosModel["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":cedula",$datosModel["cedula"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":sexo",$datosModel["sexo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":telefono",$datosModel["telefono"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":movil",$datosModel["movil"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":direccion",$datosModel["direccion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":universidad",$datosModel["universidad"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":pnf",$datosModel["pnf"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":sede",$datosModel["sede"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt-> bindParam(":vacunado",$datosModel["vacunado"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if ($stmt -> execute()) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

y esta es la parte del php de registro

```
<h1>Registrar</h1>

<form method="post">

  <input type="text" name="usuarioRegistro" placeholder="ingrese su usuario" required>
  <input type="password" name="passwordRegistro" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
  <input type="email" name="emailRegistro" placeholder="ingrese su correo" required>
  <input type="text" name="cedulaRegistro" placeholder="ingrese su cedula" required>
  <input type="text" name="telefonoRegistro" placeholder=" ingrese su numero de telefono" required>
  <input type="text" name="movilRegistro" placeholder="ingrese el numero del movil" required>
  <input type="text" name="direccionRegistro" placeholder="ingrese su direccion" required>
  <input type="text" name="universidadRegistro" placeholder="Ingrese su universidad" required>
  <input type="text" name="pnfRegistro" placeholder="ingrese el pnf donde esta" required>
  <input type="text" name="sedeRegistro" placeholder=" ingrese su sede" required>
  <input type="text" name="sexoRegistro" placeholder="sexo " required>
  <input type="text" name="vacunadoRegistro" placeholder="esta vacunado? si/no" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>

<?php
$registro = new MvcController();
$registro -> registroUsuarioController();

if(isset($_GET["action"])){
    if($_GET["action"] == "ok"){
        echo "registro exitoso";
    }
}

?>
```

y esta la del controlador

```php
    #registro de usuarios
    #---------------------------------------------------
    public function registroUsuarioController(){

        if(isset($_POST["usuario"])){

            $datosController = array(
                "usuario" => $_POST["usuarioRegistro"],
                "password" => $_POST["passwordRegistro"],
                "email" => $_POST["emailRegistro"], 
                "cedula" => $_POST["cedulaRegistro"],
                "sexo" => $_POST["sexoRegistro"],
                "telefono" => $_POST["telefonoRegistro"],
                "movil" => $_POST["movilRegistro"],
                "direccion" => $_POST["direccionRegistro"],
                "universidad" => $_POST["universidadRegistro"],
                "pnf" => $_POST["pnfRegistro"],
                "sede" => $_POST["sedeRegistro"],
                "vacunado" => $_POST["vacunadoRegistro"]
            );

            $respuesta = (new Datos)->registroUsuarioModel($datosController, "usuarios");

            if($respuesta == "success"){
                header("location:index.php?action=ok");
            } else {
                header("location:index.php");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mientras revisamos el código, ¿por qué no estás implementando control de errores? Si lo hicieras, ya sabrías por qué falla tu código.

Comment: Primer error: no estás poniendo el marcador `:direccion` en la consulta SQL. En fase de depuración, para ver con claridad los errores, considera usar [`errorInfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php) o activar **provisionalmente** en tu entorno PHP el despliegue de mensajes de error.

Comment: ok revisare como implementarlo, es de un trabajo para la uni y no habia escuchado o aprendido antes eso, investigare como implementar el control de errores, gracias

Comment: Tú puedes crear un archivo `.php` con estas tres líneas: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` y lo puedes incluir **temporalmente** en aquellos archivos que estés creando/modificando. Esto te mostrará en pantalla cualquier error y donde ocurre, ganando horas y hasta días depurando tu código, al saber las fallas con exactitud. Si no sabes resolverlas, puedes preguntar aquí, agregando el código relevante y el mensaje de error. De lo contrario habrá que empezar a hurgar en el código hasta dar con el problema.

Comment: perfecto, hare eso, de verdad muchas gracias por tomar el tiempo de responder, lo aplicare a mi codigo, y viene perfecto ya que al registrarme no da ningun error y con esto prodria saber si hay un error que no me lo este mostrando y por eso no me esta funcionando, de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: Sí, además eso te permitirá resolver los `Wargnins` y los `Notice`, que no son errores graves, pero que están ahí sobrecargando y escribiendo quizá en los logs de error... al cabo del tiempo podrías tener logs de varios Mb o de Gb, llenos de `Warnings` y de `Notice`  u otros. Pero, **no olvides quitar el include del archivo que muestra los errores, una vez el código esté listo para pasar a producción**, o sea, cuando esté limpio y no emita ningún error, ni warning, ni notice, ni nada de nada.

Comment: perfecto, Muchas gracias :D

Comment: Y, si quieres mejorar tu proyecto, considera usar Ajax, así no necesitarás estar recargando la página cada vez y redirigiendo. Con Ajax (o la nueva API Fetch) podrás mandar y traer cosas entre cliente y servidor sin recargas de página. Cuando puedas échale una mirada. Pero, volviendo al problema, ¿ya se corrigió? ¿Empezaste a mostrar los errores? ¿Qué errores tienes? Puedes pulsar en [edit] para agregar los errores en la pregunta.

Comment: Te falta `direccion` en los valores de la tabla...

Comment: ok perfecto lo mas pronto vere como usar Ajax, y no aun no lo resuelvo implemente el control de errores pero no me marca ninguno pienso que es un error logico con esto en el crud, if ($stmt -> execute()){
            return "success";
        }else{
            return "error";
        } }
 y en el controller 
        if($respuesta == "success"){
            header("location:index.php?action=ok");
        }
        else{
            header("location:index.php");
        } ya que si se estaria ejecutando el codigo pero siendo success falso al registrar por lo que vuelve al index

Comment: Sí, puede haber un error de clave duplicada u otro. Puedes hacer lo siguiente, en el método de inserción: `if ($stmt -> execute()){ return array("status"=>"success"); }else{ return array("status"=>"error", "msg"=>$stmt->errorInfo()[2]);}` y donde recibes la respuesta, verificas de este modo: `if ( array_key_exists('error', $respuesta) ) { $msg=$response["msg"]; header("location:index.php?error=$msg"); } else { header("location:index.php?action=ok"); }`  Y en `index.php` puedes poner un `var_dump($_GET);` para ver el mensaje de error que estás recibiendo...

Comment: ... Es un rollazo trabajar con redirecciones, todo esto sería sumamente simple con Ajax, pero en fin, espero que pronto puedas implementar Ajax o Fetch. La cuestión es que un programa serio debe informar al usuario de los errores (no con errores internos del programa, sino con mensajes personalalizados). Aquí, para depurar usamos `errorInfo()`, pero deberías pensar en implementar una política de manejo de errores. Es algo que se suele descuidar, pero no podemos decir que un programa está bien hecho, si no se manejan los errores adecuadamente.